# Three JS Animation Screen Blank

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new to three js and webgl. I have a complicated solar system I'm building and it all works great until I want to animate anything. Here is a very stripped down version to show the problem (with sun in low res). If I add the line sun.rotate.y += 1; it wont load or run anything at all. I have looked around a lot and can't figure out why. I'm sure it is something stupid I'm missing. Thanks for any help.

```
<script>

    // SETUP SCENE

    var camera, controls, scene, renderer;
    var container

    init();
    animate();

    function init() {

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 90000 );
        camera.position.z = 100;

        controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );

        controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
        controls.zoomSpeed = .2;
        controls.panSpeed = 0.8;

        controls.noZoom = false;
        controls.noPan = true;

        controls.staticMoving = false;
        controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;

        controls.keys = [ 65, 83, 68 ];

        controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );


        scene = new THREE.Scene();


        // ADD THE SUN PHYSICAL LOCATION
        var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 3, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "Yellow"});
        var sun = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(sun);

        //RENDER
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false } );
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
        container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        render();
        animate();


    }

    function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            controls.handleResize();

            render();

    }

    function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            controls.update();

            render();    
    }


    function render() {
            sun.rotate.y +=1; // Problem animating?
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }

</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `sun` as a global variable because currently it is not visible in the `render()` scope.

Also, I think to rotate a mesh you call "rotateX(), rotateY() or rotateZ()" so it is `sun.rotateY(0.01)`

Edit: I realized you can rotate the mesh by modifying its `rotation` rather than its `rotate` property.

Comment: Little confused. The sun renders fine without being a global variable. I can render and interact with the camera to pan around it ect. It only stops working when I try to add the rotation animation?

Comment: Did you try using "rotation" instead of "rotate"? Also, what version of three.js are you using?

Comment: Yes, I updated to use the sun.rotation.y += 1; I'm on the latest version of three js. Just downloaded it yesterday. I also declared the variable sun before any functions. Still no go....

Comment: I made a quick plunker and it seems to work
https://plnkr.co/edit/PQOtTdv0wThsyQ0jfu9M , I commented out trackball stuff and had the camera looking down the z axis

Comment: Okay, cool. That is working. I'll see if I can figure out what you did. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so declaring the sun before the functions, removing var from the declaration in the function, and changing property to .rotation fixed. it. thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have a scope issue ( well it's complicated depending on what you  are using es6 or es5), these are the offending bits:

Declare your global(or not Js will add it) to the global space :

```
var container, sun;
```

And refer to it inside the init function:

```
this.sun = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

Working Pen:

[Scope Issue in Three.js](http://codepen.io/k3no/pen/wzLxdX?editors=0011)

Also, TrackballControls is not part of Three.js, you have to import it, check the pen.

Also, Also,for the rotation you might want to use:

```
sun.rotation.y += 0.003;
```